# Apply/Maintain status over period of time

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, window-functions

Given this dataset,  John has a snapshot per year of his stock holdings.

I would like the data to be marked such that the earliest bought stock in his portfolio which still exists is marked as Primary.

For instance, given this dataset

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
| Name | Year | Stock | Value |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| John | 2020 | ABC   |   123 |
| John | 2021 | ABC   |   123 |
| John | 2021 | XYZ   |   200 |
| John | 2022 | ABC   |   123 |
| John | 2022 | XYZ   |   200 |
| John | 2022 | JKL   |   500 |
| John | 2023 | XYZ   |   200 |
| John | 2023 | JKL   |   500 |
+------+------+-------+-------+
```

I would like the data to be marked as this:

```
+------+------+-------+-------+------------+
| Name | Year | Stock | Value | Is_Primary |
+------+------+-------+-------+------------+
| John | 2020 | ABC   |   123 | Yes        |
| John | 2021 | ABC   |   123 | Yes        |
| John | 2021 | XYZ   |   200 |            |
| John | 2022 | ABC   |   123 | Yes        |
| John | 2022 | XYZ   |   200 |            |
| John | 2022 | JKL   |   500 |            |
| John | 2023 | XYZ   |   200 | Yes        |
| John | 2023 | JKL   |   500 |            |
+------+------+-------+-------+------------+
```

In 2020, John holds ABC, which is Primary as it is the only one.

In 2021, John holds ABC but has also acquired XYZ, but ABC is still his primary as it is the first one to be added.

in 2022, John holds ABC and XYZ, and has added JKL, but ABC is still his primary.

In 2023, John no longer holds ABC, and so XYZ is marked as primary. In the situation in which multiple stocks are added in the same year, I would like for the earliest alphabetically to be marked as Primary.

How would I do this, whether it be through functions in PL/SQL or in pure SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using window functions:

```
select name, year, stock, value,
    case when 
        row_number() 
            over(partition by name, year  order by first_year_added, stock)
        = 1 then 'yes' 
    end is_primary
from (
    select
        t.*,
        min(year) over(partition by name, stock) first_year_added
    from mytable t
) t
```

The subquery computes the first year when each `stock` was added for each `name`. Then, the outer query uses that information to rank records having the same `name` and `year`: the record that gets the first rank gets the flag.

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b66bdae643aef7c630014c83f8bc18fc)**:

```
NAME | YEAR | STOCK | VALUE | IS_PRIMARY
:--- | ---: | :---- | ----: | :---------
John | 2020 | ABC   |   123 | yes       
John | 2021 | ABC   |   123 | yes       
John | 2021 | XYZ   |   200 | null      
John | 2022 | ABC   |   123 | yes       
John | 2022 | XYZ   |   200 | null      
John | 2022 | JKL   |   500 | null      
John | 2023 | XYZ   |   200 | yes       
John | 2023 | JKL   |   500 | null
```